# Multiplying large numbers through strings

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write a program that will receive 2 strings representing numbers of any length
(for instance, `char *a = "10000000000000";`, `char *b = "9999999999999999";`) and multiply them.
This is what I came up with so far, not sure how to continue (`nullify` simply fills the whole string with '0'):

```
char *multiply(char *hnum, const char *other)
{
    int num1=0, num2=0, carry=0, hnumL=0, otherL=0, i=0, temp1L=0, temp2L=0, n=0;
    char *temp1, *temp2;
    if(!hnum || !other) return NULL;

    for(hnumL=0; hnum[hnumL] != '\0'; hnumL++);
    for(otherL=0; other[otherL] != '\0'; otherL++);

    temp1 = (char*)malloc(otherL+hnumL);
    if(!temp1) return NULL;
    temp2 = (char*)malloc(otherL+hnumL);
    if(!temp2) return NULL;
    nullify(temp1);
    nullify(temp2);

    hnumL--;
    otherL--;
    for(otherL; otherL >= 0; otherL--)
    {
        carry = 0;
        num1 = other[otherL] - '0';
        for(hnumL; hnumL >= 0; hnumL--)
        {
            num2 = hnum[hnumL] - '0';
            temp1[i+n] = (char)(((int)'0') + ((num1 * num2 + carry) % 10));
            carry = (num1 * num2 + carry) / 10;
            i++;
            temp1L++;
        }
        if(carry > 0)
        {
            temp1[i+n] = (char)(((int)'0') + carry);
            temp1L++;

        }
```

p.s. Is there a library that handles this already? Couldn't find anything like it.

Comment: it's complicated, it would be good if you write comments

Comment: You don't ask a question here. You should do so. That said, I'm not sure why you would be reinventing this particular wheel. Surely it's better to use an existing library.

Comment: @David Heffernan the question is how to continue this, or if there's a better way to do it, what is it? I'm not aware of any library that handles this and didn't find anything like that...

Comment: There are loads of libraries that do this already. I can't imagine why you would ignore them. If you do have a question you must ask it in the question and not in comments. That said, "how to continue" is not a valid question. You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: If you are really struggling with your websearch, then you might care to start here: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: How would you to that with paper and pencil? You can do just the same with C.

Answer (score 1):

On paper, you would probably do as follows:

```
 999x99
--------
   8991
  8991
========  
   98901
```

The process is to multiply individual digits starting from the right of each number and adding them up keeping a carry in mind each time ("9 times 9 equals 81, write 1, keep 8 in mind"). I'm pretty sure you covered that in elementary school, didn't you?.

The process can be easily put into an algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct result
{
    int carry;
    int res;
};

/*
 * multiply two numbers between 0 and 9 into result.res. If there is a carry, put it into
 * result.carry
 */
struct result mul(int a, int b)
{
    struct result res;

    res.res = a * b;
    if (res.res > 9)
    {
        res.carry = res.res / 10;
        res.res %= 10;
    }
    else
        res.carry = 0;

    return res;
}

/*
 * add
 * adds a digit (b) to str at pos. If the result generates a carry,
 * it's added also (recursively)
 */
add(char str[], int pos, int b)
{
    int res;
    int carry;

    res = str[pos] - '0' + b;
    if (res > 9)
    {
        carry = res / 10;
        res %= 10;
        add(str, pos - 1, carry);
    }
    str[pos] = res + '0';
}

void nullify(char *numstr, int len)
{
    while (--len >= 0)
        numstr[len] = '0';
}

int main(void)
{
    struct result res;
    char *mp1 = "999";
    char *mp2 = "999";
    char sum[strlen(mp1) + strlen(mp2) + 1];

    int i;
    int j;

    nullify(sum, strlen(mp1) + strlen(mp2));

    for (i = strlen(mp2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        /* iterate from right over second multiplikand */
        for (j = strlen(mp1) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            /* iterate from right over first multiplikand */
            res = mul((mp2[i] - '0'), (mp1[j] - '0'));
            add(sum, i + j + 1, res.res);   /* add sum */
            add(sum, i + j, res.carry);     /* add carry */
        }
    }

    printf("%s * %s = %s\n", mp1, mp2, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

This is just the same as on paper, except that you don't need to remember individual summands since we add up everything on the fly.

This might not bee the fastest way to do it, but it doesn't need `malloc()` (provided you have a C99 compiler, otherwise you would need to dynamically allocate `sum`) and works for arbitrarily long numbers (up to the stack limit since `add()` is implemented as recursive function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are libraries that handle this. It's actually a pretty big subject area that a lot of research has gone into. I haven't looked through your code that closely, but I know that the library implementations of big num operations have [very efficient algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) that you're unlikely to discover on your own.  FOr example, the multiplication routine we all learned in grade school (pre common-core) is a O(n^2) solution to multiplication, but there exist ways to solve it in ~O(n^1.5).

THe standard GNU c big num library is GNU MP

https://gmplib.org/